Mocking Modules with Pdoc3
NOTE: Based on the things I have found, I am tempted to assume that this issue continues to be unresolved, but I'll try to ask here anyway just in case.
I work using a program that supports Python scripting for automation of tasks. However, a lot of the scripting is heavily reliant on modules and packages that only exist inside the program's environment when it's running.
I am now trying to document all of the scripts I've created for this program. However, it seems like a lot of documentation tools don't have an easy way to mock these modules and packages.
So far, I've found the most success using Sphinx, but the configuration process is rather specific and I'd like to be able to simplify it as I am working with a team that is not specialized in programming.
Pdoc3 seems to be a much simpler solution, but I don't think there's a way to mock or ignore modules with it. As far as I understand it, I would have to go inside the original scripts I've already created and attempt to mock them directly from the source.
Is there way to tell Pdoc3 to mock modules it can't find?
And, if not, what is the best way to mock these imported modules so I can document them using Pdoc3?
